# Flush() required for multiple Eclipselink merges in the same transaction?

Tags: oracle10g, eclipselink, entitymanager

I'm having an issue with multiple `EntityManager.merge()` calls in a single transaction.  This is using an Oracle database.  Neither object exists yet.  Entities:

```
public class A {
    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    public Long getID();

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = B.class)
    @JoinColumn("ID")
    public B getB();
}

public class B {
    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    public Long getID();
}
```

The merge code looks something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void create(Object A, Object B) {
    Object A = entitymanager.merge(A);
    B.setId(A.getId());
    entitymanager.merge(B);
}
```

Object A's ID is generated through a sequence and it gets correctly set on B.  Looking at the log, merge on A is called before merge on B is called.  There is a @OneToOne mapping from A to B.  However, at the end of the method when it goes to actually commit, it tries to do an INSERT on B before it goes to do an INSERT on A, which throws an `IntegrityConstraintViolation` because the "parent key not found".

If I add `entitymanager.flush()` before the 2nd merge, it works fine.

```
@Transactional
public void create(Object A, Object B) {
    Object A = entitymanager.merge(A);
    entitymanager.flush();
    B.setId(A.getId());
    entitymanager.merge(B);
}
```

However, `flush()` is an expensive operation that shouldn't be necessary.  All of this should be happening in the same transaction (default propagation of `@Transactional` is `Propagation.REQUIRED`).

Any idea why this doesn't work without `flush()`, and why even though the merge on A happens before the merge on B, the actual INSERT on COMMIT is reversed?

Answer (score 0):

If entity A and B do not have a relationship (i.e. @OneToOne, @OneToMany, ...), then the persistence provider cannot calculate the correct insertion order. IIRC EclipseLink does not use the object-creation order when it comes to sending SQL statements to the database.

If you like to refrain from using flush(), simply set your constraints to be deferred.

Comment: A and B do have an `@OneToOne` relationship as far as I know, the following method is on Object A:

    `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, optional = true, targetEntity = B.class)

    public B getB() {}`

Comment: By "set your constraints to be deferred," are you referencing not having the Foreign Key constraint in the database?  That doesn't seem like a good option either.  I would have to think there has to be a way to enforce the order of the `INSERT` statements in Eclipselink.

Answer (score 0):

As Frank mentioned, the code you have shown does not set a A->B relationship, so there is no way for the provider to know that this B object needs to be inserted before the A.  Other relationships may cause it to think that in general A needs to be inserted first.

Deferring constraints can be done on some databases, and refers to setting the database to defer constraint processing until the end of the transaction.  If you defer or remove the constraints, you can then see if the SQL that is being generated is correct or if there is another problem with the code and mappings that is being missed.

Comment: I should have specified that there is a join relationship setup in A.  This doesn't seem to be sufficient.  Eclipselink not following the merge order doesn't make sense to me either.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the merges are alphabetical (at least, that is one possibility) unless there are bidirectional @OneToOne annotations.

Previously:

```
public class A {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = B.class)
    @JoinColumn("ID")
    public B getB();
}

public class B {
    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    public Long getID();
}
```

Now:

```
public class A {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = B.class)
    @JoinColumn("ID")
    public B getB();
}

public class B {
    @Id
    @Column("ID")
    public Long getID();

    @OneToOne(targetEntity = A.class)
    @JoinColumn("ID")
    public A getA();
}
```

For what I'm doing it doesn't matter that B has a way to get A, but I still don't understand why the annotations in A aren't sufficient.